# multiple random columns with CSS

Tags: css, multiple-columns

Div has a fixed height (ex. 400px) and in that div there is random text (ex. 100 or 1000 chars). When text is long css makes wide div with 5 columns (200px each) with horizontal scrolling, and when text is short div is norrow and has only 2 columns.

Is it possible in CSS?

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible using **ONLY** CSS. However, it certainly is achievable using JavaScript.

If you're willing to use JavaScript, I would suggest calculating the number of characters within the `<div>`, and then adjusting the column formatting accordingly.

You can get the number of characters in a div using jQuery: `$('#mydiv').text().length`

Comment: thx.I've got other idea. check in javascript weather height of div is more then containers - if yes add column and widen container. I'll try

Comment: Yes, that can work. Good luck and feel free to ask if you have any questions.